# If only chivalry were dead or was dead?

Tags: grammar

The phrase "if only chivalry were dead" sounds right, but is it grammatically wrong? I would like to know if I should be using 'were' or 'was'. This is for a mock press release for university.

Comment: ***If only***: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/conditionals-and-wishes/if-only

Answer (score 1):

"If only chivalry were dead"is perfectly correct and can be explained under the grammatical structure known as subjunctive mood - wishful expressions. Another example is: I wish I were there. This implies that I was not there and regret that. If "was" were to be used, the sentence would not achieve the same effect and possibly meaning too.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, "be" is being used in a past tense (or past subjunctive tense).

When used with *I*, *we*, *you*, and *they*, the correct past tense form of "be" is **were**.

When used with *he*, *she*, or *it*, the correct past tense form of "be" is **was**.

That being said, the subjunctive form allows for **were** to be used in all above situations, and sounds more formal.

Therefore, the correct phrase, IMO, would be:

> **If only chivalry were dead.**